# How do I boot Windows XP install from removable CD drive?

Tags: windows-xp, boot, usb

I know the drill for installing linux via USB, and normally I can install Windows via sata CD drive. I thought this would be no different, but for some reason, my bios is showing my 3 hard drives available but does not show the cd drive as an option to boot from. The removable drive option, the usb option, and the Optical Drive option are all "Enabled" in the bios.

Is there a way I can install XP from my USB portable CD drive?

Comment: yea, i've personally done it many times, but your motherboard my not support it, this is a fairly new feature, i would say this feature was introduced about 2-3 years ago, but don't quote me on that. Check your motherboard settings online and see if it's possible to do this.

Comment: You may have to enable USB boot in the BIOS

Comment: @cybernard Like I mentioned in the post, I have that enabled.

Comment: @Sickest so booting from a USB CD-Rom is a special feature? I looked at the motherboard guide, but it just says to do what I've already done, which is check that USB is enabled in the bios settings and to check that it's getting enough power.

Comment: its not a "special feature" its a feature that has only been recently been supported by mother boards in the last 3-4 years, if you consider that special, ok, its special. ;p